# 'not found' error but the function is defined

Tags: scala

Using this class I'm attempting to modify the String parameter of the constructor and convert it to date :

```
  class OrderInstance(var size: Double,
                      var side: String,
                      var trade_id: Int,
                      var price: Double,
                      var time: java.util.Date,
                      var code: String) {
    def getTime(time: String): java.util.Date = new java.util.Date()
    def this(size: String,
             side: String,
             trade_id: Int,
             price: String,
             time: String, code: String) = this(size.toDouble: Double,
      side: String,
      trade_id: Int,
      price.toDouble: Double,
      getTime(time: String) : java.util.Date, code: String)



    // Step 3 - proper signature for `equals`
    // Steps 4 thru 7 - implement a `match` expression
    override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
      that match {
        case that: OrderInstance => {
          that.canEqual(this) &&
            this.trade_id == that.trade_id
        }
        case _ => false
      }

    //     Step 1 - proper signature for `canEqual`
    //     Step 2 - compare `a` to the current class
    def canEqual(a: Any) = a.isInstanceOf[OrderInstance]

    // Step 8 - implement a corresponding hashCode c=method
    override def hashCode: Int = {
      val prime = 31
      var result = 1
      result = prime * result + trade_id;
      result = prime * result + (if (code == null) 0 else code.hashCode)
      result
    }

    override def toString = {
      String.valueOf(trade_id)
    }

  }
```

This line :

```
def getTime(time: String): java.util.Date = new java.util.Date()
```

should be called in order to return a date instead of String. But I receive error :

```
Error:(54, 7) not found: value getTime
      getTime(time: String) : java.util.Date, code: String)
```

This error is reported at run time, not compile time. Have I not defined the function `getTime` correctly ?

Update :

I've attempted to make more clear what I'm trying to achieve :

```
class OrderInstance(var size: Double,
                    var side: String,
                    var trade_id: Int,
                    var price: Double,
                    var time: String,
                    var code: String){

  this(time) = this(OrderInstance.getTime(time))

  def this(size: String,
           side: String,
           trade_id: Int,
           price: String,
           time: String, code: String) = this(size.toDouble: Double,
    side: String,
    trade_id: Int,
    price.toDouble: Double,
    time : String, code: String)

  // Step 3 - proper signature for `equals`
  // Steps 4 thru 7 - implement a `match` expression
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
    that match {
      case that: OrderInstance => {
        that.canEqual(this) &&
          this.trade_id == that.trade_id
      }
      case _ => false
    }

  //     Step 1 - proper signature for `canEqual`
  //     Step 2 - compare `a` to the current class
  def canEqual(a: Any) = a.isInstanceOf[OrderInstance]

  // Step 8 - implement a corresponding hashCode c=method
  override def hashCode: Int = {
    val prime = 31
    var result = 1
    result = prime * result + trade_id;
    result = prime * result + (if (code == null) 0 else code.hashCode)
    result
  }

  override def toString = {
    String.valueOf(trade_id)
  }

}
object OrderInstance {
  def getTime(time: String): java.util.Date = new java.util.Date()
}

new OrderInstance(1.0 , "" , 1 , 1.0 , "2019-09-13T16:27:19.881Z" , "")
```

This returns error :

```
Error:(60, 26) OrderInstance does not take parameters
this(time) = this(OrderInstance.getTime(time))
```

for line

```
 this(time) = this(OrderInstance.getTime(time))
```

How to update `time` to be converted to Date instead of String ?

Comment: It's because you can't use any other function in your class inside your auxiliary constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTime` is an instance method, which you're trying to invoke from a constructor, i.e. before the instance has been created. Since `getTime` doesn't actually use any instance variables, you'll want to place it in a companion object (the scala equivalent of `static`)

```
class OrderInstance(
//...
) {
  this(string) = this(OrderInstance.getTime(string))
}

object OrderInstance {
   def getTime(time: String): java.util.Date = new java.util.Date()
}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure how to merge your code with mine. How should 'this(string) = this(OrderInstance.getTime(string))' be utilized as it is not valid as is ? Please see question update as I've tried to incorporate your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer from user user1186491 this works as expected :

```
class OrderInstance(var time: java.util.Date){

  def this(time: String) = this(
    OrderInstance.getTime(time))
}

object OrderInstance {
  def getTime(time: String): java.util.Date = new java.util.Date()
}

val o = new OrderInstance("2019-09-13T16:27:19.881Z" )
println(o.time)
```